# C appending to file after writing

Tags: c, file-io

I'm testing out the basic functions to operate files with.

I try to first open/close a file to create it, and then open/close it again to append to it. Lastly, I print out what is in the file.

My code currently looks like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  FILE * file;
  char mark;

  /* WRITING: */
  file= fopen("goodbye.c","w");
  if(!file)
    { printf("Couldn't open file.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
  printf("Enter data to write to .c file:");
  while((mark= getchar())!=EOF)
    {
      putc(mark,file);
    }
  fclose(file);

  /* APPENDING: */
  file= fopen("goodbye.c","a");
  if(!file)
    { printf("Couldn't open file.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
  char add;
  scanf("%c",add);
  putc(add,file);
  fclose(file);

  /* READING: */
  file= fopen("goodbye.c","r");
  if(!file)
    { printf("Couldn't open file.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
  while((mark= getc(file))!= EOF)
    {
      printf("%c",mark);
    }
  fclose(file);
}
```

With this, I'm not able to append to the file. When using getchar(), I type ctrl+d once finished writing in the first place. After this it goes on to printing out what I just wrote, not giving me the chance to append to the file. Does ctrl+d somehow interrupt with scanf?
And how to get the result that I was looking for?

Comment: Just open the file with the append flag: `fopen('file.txt', 'a');`. The file will be created if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @KristerAndersson: You need double quotes around strings, not the single quotes that go around character literals.

Comment: Your code only allows you to append a single character to the file, which is a little stingy.  It can also lead to problems on some systems if the last line of the text file does not end with a newline, which it won't if you add something other than a newline.  Maybe you need a loop to read multiple characters?  Also, since you don't stop the initial input until EOF, you may need to clear the error on `stdin` with `clearerr(stdin)` to allow further input to occur.

Comment: Incidentally, my compiler complains about a missing `&` in the call to `scanf()` at: `char add;
  scanf("%c",add);` — if yours doesn't, either turn up the warning level or get a better compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code only allows you to append a single character to the file, which is a little stingy. It can also (at least in theory) lead to problems on some systems if the last line of the text file does not end with a newline, which it won't if you add something other than a newline. Maybe you need a loop to read multiple characters?

Also, since you don't stop the initial input until EOF, you need to clear the 'error' on `stdin` with `clearerr(stdin)` to allow further input to occur.  This works correctly on Mac OS X 10.10.1 Yosemite; it should work the same on other Unix systems.  I can't answer confidently for Windows-based code unless it is using something like Cygwin to simulate Unix, but I expect it would work in much the same way there, too, even with MSVC.

Incidentally, my compiler complains about a missing `&` in the call to `scanf()` at:

```
char add;
scanf("%c",add);
```

If your compiler doesn't complain, either turn up the warning level or get a better compiler.

This code works as I'd expect:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file;
    char mark;

    /* WRITING: */
    file = fopen("goodbye.c", "w");
    if (!file)
    {
        printf("Couldn't open file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Enter data to write to .c file:");
    while ((mark = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        putc(mark, file);
    }
    fclose(file);
    printf("EOF 1\n");

    /* APPENDING: */
    file = fopen("goodbye.c", "a");
    if (!file)
    {
        printf("Couldn't open file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    clearerr(stdin);
    char add;
    while (scanf("%c", &add) == 1)
        putc(add, file);
    fclose(file);
    printf("EOF 2\n");

    /* READING: */
    file = fopen("goodbye.c", "r");
    if (!file)
    {
        printf("Couldn't open file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while ((mark = getc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", mark);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

The only substantive changes are adding a loop around the `scanf()` — though frankly it would be better to use `getchar()` again, like in the first input loop — fixing the call to `scanf()`, adding the two `printf()` statements that report when EOF is detected, and including `clearerr(stdin);` to allow input to continue.

#### Sample output

Code without `clearerr(stdin)`:

```
Enter data to write to .c file:Happiness is a bug-free program.
Happiness is seldom attained.
EOF 1
EOF 2
Happiness is a bug-free program.
Happiness is seldom attained.
```

Code with `clearerr(stdin)`:

```
Enter data to write to .c file:Happiness is a bug-free program.
Happiness is seldom attained.
EOF 1
But it helps when you add the clearerr(stdin) to this one.
EOF 2
Happiness is a bug-free program.
Happiness is seldom attained.
But it helps when you add the clearerr(stdin) to this one.
```

Comment: I see, thank you very much, clearerr does the job indeed! 
I wasn't sure where the problem was exactly, so I tried to simplify by adding just one character first. Why does it lead to said problems.

Comment: Also, what would be more sophisticated ways to stop getchar() from getting input? I could probably recognise ctrl+d, or some similar 'character' (that would not be pressed accidentally while trying to write to the file) in the loop?

Comment: Technically, a text file must end with a new line sequence.  If it doesn't, you might not get to read the last 'line' back in again.  It usually isn't an issue on Unix, where there isn't really a distinction between text and binary files, but it might matter more on Windows.  I also seem to remember a question here on SO where some program behaved unexpectedly when the last 'line' didn't end with a new line.

Comment: As to spotting the end of the first input, I think it's fair to say you would not often use the technique at all.  If you did, EOF works OK.  If you don't want to use that, use something that can't be valid.  A control character is a possibility; another is a line containing only a dot (a technique used in some email programs, for example).  It isn't valid C which seems to be what your user is supposed to type. (OK; it could be valid C, but it would be very contorted C.)